# xmppStreamDidConnect not getting called

Tags: ios, swift, xmpp, xmppframework

[image: **Break point in original Framework image**]I'm creating the framework in swift using Robbinson XMPP framework, I managed to set up the project, the delegate method bellow is getting called:

```
func xmppStreamWillConnect(_ sender: XMPPStream!) {
        print("will");
    }
```

but the delegate method below never gets called:

```
    func xmppStreamDidConnect(_ sender: XMPPStream!) {
            print("connected");
           /* auth func here*/
        }
```

i tried to put breakpoint in objc code, its hitting the // Notify delegates method (please ref screen shot ) but in my code its not get called ..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Catch the error while connecting to the server and check the error. Don't forget to set the jabbaerid before connecting.

```
let xmppStream = XMPPStream()
xmppStream.myJID = XMPPJID(string: "yourjabberID")
xmppStream.hostName = "yourxmppserver"
xmppStream.hostPort = 5222

do {
    try xmppStream.connect(withTimeout: XMPPStreamTimeoutNone)
    print("Connection success")
   } 
catch let error 
   {
    print(error)
   }
```